# "movie Titanic" vs "Titanic movie"

Tags: grammar

> I have seen the movie Titanic.

or

> I have seen the Titanic movie.

Which of these are correct? How do we can find the right order for these kinds of phrases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is the normal order: precede a proper name with a noun in apposition which defines or limits it: "the movie *Titanic*", "the book *Gone With the Wind*", "the opera *Carmen*", "the writer James Joyce", "the painter David Hockney".

When the proper name is geographical, you usually need "of": "the city of Ripon", "the Island of Malta", "the continent of Australia". ("River" is an odd one: in British English, it precedes the name: "the River Trent"; in American English it follows the name: "the Missouri River").

"The Titanic movie" sounds very odd to me, and I would take "titanic" as an adjective, not a name. "The Gone with the Wind movie" is comprehensible, but not normal.